# Why does using the '\b' not work when it gets to newline?

Tags: c++, newline, iostream, fstream, cout

I've been trying to read from a file to console and then clear it to read another file.
So I found out you can remove characters from console by using '\b'. However when I try to remove previous content from console it only removes the last line and then stops.

Something like this:

```
std::cout<<"Something boring"<<'\n'<<"Something boring on new line";
while(1){
std::cout<<'\b';
std::cout<<' ';
std::cout<<'\b';
}
```

This will only remove "Something boring on new line", and as far as I can see the cursor is on the first position of line 2.

Why does it get stuck and can something be done about it?
Thanks.

Comment: `'\b'` is a single backspace, why would you expect it to clear an entire line? If you want to clear the console screen, use something like `std::system("cls")` instead.

Comment: Think of it like the first `'\b'` removed the line, and second removed the `'/n'`, or the `' '` in `std::cout<<' ';`

Comment: Backspace before the start of the text line is non-standard behavior.  Some terminals (i.e. consoles) ignore it.  Others may allow wrap to end of previous line.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews OSX allows it but Linux doesn't, am I right? What should be done in case of Linux?

Comment: When I do:while(1){std::'\b'}; //without adding ' '//. Then '\b' only makes the cursor travel 1 space back and nothing gets removed. But @Remy's std::system("cls") worked so thanks. I am still interested why \b didn't work.

Comment: The behavior in Linux and Unix depends on the terminal driver.  Some drivers allow it, others don't.  Also, if your previous line scrolls beyond the buffer history, you're screwed.  Find a different technique for cursor positioning or clearing.  Think of teletypes or printers.

Comment: You might accomplish what you want if you put the output in a function something like shown here:  https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/1pb9lb/can_somebody_explain_why_id_use_a_backspace_b_in/?st=j34thnar&sh=b1c63c4c